# Change color on DatePicker

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to change on click color of cell in `DatePick` calendar?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, override the style and pass it to your layout with a `style` attribute. Additionally you can create a custom style on a per Activity basis or whole Application basis. (Acitivty styles will override Application styles.)

**Expanded for Comment**
You can use the existing DatePicker (and all widgets for that matter) as a super class. Override the existing methods and provide your customization. To help integrate your new widget with your layouts check [Modifying an Existing View Type](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#modifying) in [Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) Dev Guide article.

Comment: Hm, i want to make something like if I click 1st june than 5th june should be marked with red...I am really stuck here...